# Formatting the results of a powershell script

Tags: powershell, service, output

How can i add the server name at the left of each line result on this script?. Thank you!

```
$servers = Get-Content -path .\Machines.txt
[pscustomobject]$result = @()  
$subresult =
ForEach ($server in $servers) 
{
Set-Service -computername $servers -Name sacsvr -StartupType Disabled -PassThru
}
$result = $subresult 
$result | Out-File local_group_members.csv
```

This is an example result:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  sacsvr             Special Administration Console Helper 
Stopped  sacsvr             Special Administration Console Helper 
Stopped  sacsvr             Special Administration Console Helper
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can just add a property to the objects you're outputting right now. Pipe your Set-Service to Add-Member like this:

```
Set-Service -computername $servers -Name sacsvr -StartupType Disabled -PassThru | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Server' -Value $Server -PassThru
```

Now each object that you pass to `$subresult` has a new property `Server` that is the name of the server it was run on. You'll probably want to pipe through Select when outputting to have the order you want.

```
$SubResult | Select Server, Status, Name, DisplayName | Export-CSV 'local_group_members.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its is very helpful. Another question, how can i add something to check if the server is up (like Test-Connection) and put the result also in the Export-CVS of this script?.

Comment: That is a little more complicated, and better suited for it's own separate question. You would need to check if the server is up, and then either run Set-Service, and add a member to say that the server is up, or output that the server is down because if it's down running set-service is going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can arbitrarily re-order or add to your output with [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx). You can use [hash tables](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-hash-tables.html) to include calculated properties such as your desired ServerName.

So for each server, you can set the services and tag the output with that server name:

```
ForEach ($server in $servers) 
{
    Set-Service -computername $server -Name sacsvr -StartupType Disabled -PassThru |
    Select @{Name = 'ServerName'; Expression = {$server}}, Name, DisplayName, Status
}
```

The above is shorthand for:

```
Select-Object -Property (properties)
```

The `-Property` parameter allows you to select any arbitrary grouping of properties on the type of object being piped in. Another parameter, `-InputObject` allows us to pipe in objects by value.